# How to access the div element with a key in React JS? (react-dnd)

Tags: css, reactjs

This is a small app created using react-beautiful-dnd. I want to add individual css element for different key values passed through this div element. However I am unable to access this specific div element for the specific key value in css.

```
<div key={key} className={"column"}>
             <ProjectWrapper className="border">
               <hr className="hr"></hr>
             <h3 className="title">{data.title}</h3>
             </ProjectWrapper>
```

The entire source code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import _ from "lodash";
import {v4} from "uuid";

const item = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Clean the house"
}

const item2 = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Wash the car"
}

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    //creating 3 columns
    "todo": {
      title: "Todo",
      items: [item, item2]//temporary data valuesa
    },
    "in-progress": {
      title: "In Progress",
      items: []
    },
    "done": {
      title: "Completed",
      items: []
    }
  })

  const handleDragEnd = ({destination, source}) => {
    if (!destination) {
      return
    }

    if (destination.index === source.index && destination.droppableId === source.droppableId) {
      return
    }

    // Creating a copy of item before removing it from state
    const itemCopy = {...state[source.droppableId].items[source.index]}

    setState(prev => {
      prev = {...prev}
      // Remove from previous items array
      prev[source.droppableId].items.splice(source.index, 1)


      // Adding to new items array location
      prev[destination.droppableId].items.splice(destination.index, 0, itemCopy)

      return prev
    })
  }

  const addItem = () => {
    setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        todo: {
          title: "Todo",
          items: [
            {
              id: v4(),
              name: text
            },
            ...prev.todo.items
          ]
        }
      }
    })

    setText("")
  }
  //the dragdropcontext is the wrapper for draging elements
  //dropable is the certain area inside the column where u can drop items
  //dragble are the items in the column to be dragged



  //here {_.map(state, (data, key) => { 
    //the above function is used to return the data and key of all 3 elements mentioned under use state() above
    //the key: returns todo,inprogress,and done
    //where as the data returns all the values of the variables within each key
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
   
        {_.map(state, (data, key) => {
          return(
            <div key={key} className={"column"}>
              <h3>{data.title}</h3>
              <Droppable droppableId={key}>
                {(provided, snapshot) => {
                  return(
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.droppableProps}
                      key = {"Todo"}
                      className={"droppable-col"}
                    >
                      {data.items.map((el, index) => {
                        return(
                          <Draggable key={el.id} index={index} draggableId={el.id}>
                            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                              console.log(snapshot)
                              return(
                                <div
                                  className={`item ${snapshot.isDragging && "dragging"}`}
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                >
                                  {el.name}
                                </div>
                              )
                            }}
                          </Draggable>
                        )
                      })}
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                  )
                }}
              </Droppable>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `different key values passed through this div element`?

Comment: In this specific code, in the div tag a key value is passed. this key takes values such as "todo" , "inprogress" and "done". So based on these key values I want to add individual css elements

Comment: <div key={key} className={"column"}>
             <ProjectWrapper className="border">
               <hr className="hr"></hr>
             <h3 className="title">{data.title}</h3>
             </ProjectWrapper>

Comment: Your `<div>` has a custom property `key`. Access this property in CSS simply with a selector pattern like `[key="...."] { whatever css }`. E.g. with key="address" you could do something like `[key="address"] { font-size: 1.1em; color: green }`. Have a look at [W3S: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Ah, shoot, I read 'to add individual' as 'to access ...'. My bad, but maybe this still works for you, leaving my comment as is (for now).

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using a utility like [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx)

It will apply the specific class based on your value like so:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

export default function App() {
  const key = 'todo'; // or 'in-progress' or 'done'

  return (
    <div className={clsx('existingClass', key)}>
      .
      .
      .
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which renders as `<div class="existingClass todo">...</div>`. You can configure your CSS classnames for the dynamic values. (in this case, `todo`)

```js
// https://github.com/lukeed/clsx/blob/master/src/index.js
// MIT © Luke Edwards
function toVal(mix) {
    var k, y, str='';

    if (typeof mix === 'string' || typeof mix === 'number') {
        str += mix;
    } else if (typeof mix === 'object') {
        if (Array.isArray(mix)) {
            for (k=0; k < mix.length; k++) {
                if (mix[k]) {
                    if (y = toVal(mix[k])) {
                        str && (str += ' ');
                        str += y;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (k in mix) {
                if (mix[k]) {
                    str && (str += ' ');
                    str += k;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}

function clsx() {
    var i=0, tmp, x, str='';
    while (i < arguments.length) {
        if (tmp = arguments[i++]) {
            if (x = toVal(tmp)) {
                str && (str += ' ');
                str += x
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
// https://github.com/lukeed/clsx/blob/master/src/index.js
// MIT © Luke Edwards
//-------------------

function App() {
  const key = ['todo', 'in-progress', 'done'];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {key.map((k) => (
        <span className={clsx('text', k)}>{k} - </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.text{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 12px;
}

.todo {
  color: orange;
}

.in-progress {
  color: magenta;
}

.done {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```